# Controller Action 404

Tags: controller, routing, 404

Ok once again I'm having an issue with a plugin controller. It was working once upon a time but stopped sometime in the past year.

I have stripped the plugin down to bare, so there is no reason it shouldn't be working.

File Structure:

```
craft/plugins/
--webmentionreceiver/
----controllers/
------WebMentionReceiver_EndpointController.php
----WebMentionReceiverPlugin.php
```

craft/plugins/webmentionreceiver/controllers/WebMentionReceiver_EndpointController.php:

```
<?php
    namespace Craft;

    class WebMentionReceiver_EndpointController extends BaseController  {
                protected $allowAnonymous = array("actionReceive");

                public function actionReceive()  {
                        $this->redirect('/');
                }
        }
?>
```

So the plugin name is `WebMentionReceiver`, the controller is `Endpoint` and the action is `Receive`. So `index.php?p=actions/webmentionreceiver/endpoint/receive` should be the URL. But it 404s.

Any ideas? It is driving me mad!

Comment: Does camel casing the plugin name do anything so: 'webMentionReceiver' ?

Comment: Yes! That has worked. Thanks so much. Didn't realise the URL would be case sensitive.

Comment: @AlecRitson Could you post camel casing the URL as an answer please? Then I can choose it :)

Comment: No worries! Glad it helped, tried to give a bit more info in the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your plugin has a camel cased name you need to make sure you camel case your references to it, such as when you try and visit an action url.

I assume this is due to when craft tries to resolve the url it sees `pluginname` and `pluginName` as two different things, much like php variables.

I would also assume this is due to the way Craft autoloads classes.

So using `webMentionReciever` would resolve since it would be a "exact" match to your plugin name.

This isn't limited to just plugin names, the same goes for any service, controller etc references too.